# Запрос T-SQL на выборку сумм столбцов последних 5-ти строк и последней хронологической даты

Tags: sql-server

Есть две таблицы с некоторым количеством строк, в таблице `DeltaDay` нужно вычислить сумму только пяти последних строк и вставить полученные результаты в таблицу `DeltaWeek`. Проблема в следующем: следующий запрос почему-то вычисляет сумму не последних пяти, а всех строк, хотя дату выводит правильно. Вставка в таблицу `DeltaWeek` проходит без ошибок. Помогите усовершенствовать запрос для получения нужных результатов:

```
INSERT INTO DeltaWeek ( Дата ,BUY, SELL, Delta)
SELECT   DataTbl.Дата AS Data 
        ,BuyTbl.BUY AS Buy 
        ,SellTbl.SELL AS Sell 
        ,(BuyTbl.BUY - SellTbl.SELL) AS Delta 
FROM  (   --получаем дату 
      SELECT TOP 1 (Дата) as Дата 
      FROM DeltaDay 
      ORDER BY Дата DESC 
     --GROUP BY Дата 
) DataTbl 
— получаем сумму по купле 
,(
    SELECT TOP 5 SUM(BUY) AS BUY 
    FROM DeltaDay 
    ORDER BY BUY DESC 
) BuyTbl 
--получаем сумму по продаже 
,(
    SELECT TOP 5 SUM(SELL) AS SELL 
    FROM DeltaDay 
    ORDER BY SELL DESC 
) SellTbl
```

Должны получиться следующие результаты:

```
Дата         Buy        Sell       Delta
14.12.2018   13132630   15316707   -2184077
```

Таблицу с данными и результат прилагаю на скриншоте, как видно, результаты отличаются от желаемых.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы думаете `select top 5 sum()` вам вдруг посчитает сумму последних 5 строк? оно вернет вам одну строку с общей суммой. `top 5` будет применено к результату запроса, который будет одной строкой суммы.

Comment: более того, в такой записи это не последние (по дате) 5 строк. вы сортируете по уменьшению `buy` и `sell`. так что это потенциальная сумма наименьших значений.

Comment: Дайте вопросу нормальное название плиз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько можно судить из описания, то вам нужно взять последнюю дату, и посчитать суммы столбцов `buy` и `sell` в последних 5 строках таблицы

вот так и сделайте: отсортируйте по дате, возьмите первые 5 строк. Затем из полученного возьмите максимальную дату, и сумму столбцов из полученного

```
WITH data AS (
   SELECT TOP 5 [дата], sell, buy
   FROM DeltaDay
   ORDER BY [дата] DESC

)
SELECT max([дата]) as d
      ,sum(sell) as sell
      ,sum(buy) as buy
FROM data;
```

или то же самое с подзапросом вместо cte.

Comment: В этой тестовой таблице на первый взгляд всё в порядке и запрос работает. Однако, в реальной таблице есть более ранние даты которые и расположены также в верхних строчках таблицы. Почему в этом запросе дата 30.11.2018 оказывается последней, когда в таблице физически она находится на верхних строчках и хронологически также наступает раньше. Но, запрос почему-то выбирает именно её? Все даты в таблице идут в хронологическом порядке.

Comment: @ПроперМистер сортировка же указана `order by [дата] desc`. сначала данные сортируются, потом выбираются 5 строк.

Comment: Тогда почему запрос не выбирает дату 29.11.2018?

Comment: по крайней мере потому. что выбирается `max([дата])`, то есть последняя дата из доступных. у вас поле даты то какой тип имеет `date` или `varchar` ?

Comment: дата имеет тип varchar

Comment: @ПроперМистер храните данные в предназначенных для этого форматах. Если дата хранится в виде строки, то сравнение лексикографическое, и `24.12.2018` будет меньше чем `25.11.2018`.

Comment: Изменил на date - вроде, заработало...

Comment: Дело в том, что я получаю дату из таблицы сервера в формате varchar...

Comment: если формат нормальный, то это  не помешает вам вставить это значение в date-поле.